# Where does the "knife edge" sit with respect to the pivot studs?

Tags: electric-guitar, setup, tremolo-system

I am setting up an Ibanez RG350DX that I just bought.
It looks like the trem (Edge III, I think) is sitting closer to the neck than it ought to. Having never set up a floating bridge before, I need to know where the trem should sit with respect to the pivot studs.

It looks like the pivot studs are screws that have roughly a 5mm "head". Is the knife edge of the trem supposed to rest on this "head"?

Currently it's not on the head of the pivot stud, but it's below it.

like this

```
[-]  (the screw head)
 |<- (the knife edge of the trem)
```

should it be like this?

```
[-]<-  (knife edge resting on head)
 |
```

EDIT:

I just removed the tremolo and discovered that my pivot studs actually look like this

```
[-]
\ /
_|_ <-- (guessing that the knife edge fits cozily in here)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edge sits right in the slot underneath the head, but above the area that is threaded.  Just like your last picture.

Here's a nice diagram, scroll down to see it http://www.thefret.net/showthread.php/12486-Ibanez-Edge-Tremolo-Knife-Edges